# Working with specific Worksheet and selecting range; runtime error 91

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to grab a certain column in one worksheet and (eventually..no code written yet) copy it over to another worksheet in another workbook. I am getting a runtime error 91, and when I try to find a way around it, I will get a runtime error 1004.

```
Sub User_Rolee()
    Dim UserRoleWkb As Workbook, ConfigWkb As Workbook, UserRoleWkst As Worksheet, ConfigWkst As Worksheet
    Set UserRoleWkb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\clara\Desktop\S_User_Role_Map_TEMPLATE_V2_BLANK.xlsx")
    Set ConfigWkb = ActiveWorkbook
    'Set ConfigWkb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\clara\Desktop\Configuration Workbook - Paramaribo.xlsm")
    Set UserRoleWkst = UserRoleWkb.Sheets("Users")
    Set ConfigWkst = ConfigWkb.ActiveSheet
    Dim rng, rnga As Range

    With ConfigWkst
        Set rng = .Columns(2).Find(What:="Procurement Agent")
        Set rnga = .rng.Offset(1) 'runtime error 91
        Set rngar = .Range(rnga, rnga.End(xlDown)).Select
    End With        
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to check your find result for `Is Nothing` before you call `.Offset` on it.

Comment: change "Set ConfigWkb = ActiveWorkbook" to "Set ConfigWkb = ThisWorkbook". You open UserRoleWkb prior to the line which makes *THAT* the active workbook. *Edit* for good practice also define rng as range, comma seperated dims dont all inherit the last one you state.

Comment: Using `Set ConfigWkst = ConfigWkb.ActiveSheet` is too risky, and not reliable, you better of using `Set ConfigWkst = ConfigWkb.Worksheets("YourSheetName")`

Comment: Can you use a single digit in an offset call?  I'm thinking it should be "Set rnga = .rng.Offset(0,1)"

Comment: Also, `Dim rng, rnga As Range` means `rng As Variant` and only `rnga As Range`, change it to `Dim rng As Range , rnga As Range`

Comment: [Run-time error 91](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/8917/vba-run-time-errors/27750/run-time-error-91-object-variable-or-with-block-variable-not-set#t=201702171740386236498) on Documentation.SO should shed some light on the error you're getting.

Comment: @JohnMuggins sure you can, that will be the `RowOffSet` parameter. Both `OffSet` parameters are optional, and since you can't tell just by looking at the code which is the row and which is the column, it's probably better to name the argument and do `.OffSet(RowOffSet:=1)` instead.. but that's just for readability - `.OffSet(1)` isn't an error-causing problem.

Comment: That's why I love coming here.  Learn something every time! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following my comments above, try the code below:

(see my comment in the line before last, you also never defined `rngar` anywhere).

```
Option Explicit

Sub User_Rolee()

Dim UserRoleWkb As Workbook, ConfigWkb As Workbook, UserRoleWkst As Worksheet, ConfigWkst As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range, rnga As Range, rngar  As Range

Set UserRoleWkb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\clara\Desktop\S_User_Role_Map_TEMPLATE_V2_BLANK.xlsx")
Set ConfigWkb = ThisWorkbook

'Set ConfigWkb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\clara\Desktop\Configuration Workbook - Paramaribo.xlsm")
Set UserRoleWkst = UserRoleWkb.Sheets("Users")
Set ConfigWkst = ConfigWkb.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<-- modify "Sheet1" to your sheet's name

With ConfigWkst
    Set rng = .Columns(2).Find(What:="Procurement Agent")

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then '<-- find was successful
        Set rnga = rng.Offset(1)
        Set rngar = Range(rnga, rnga.End(xlDown))
        rngar.Copy '<-- copy the Range
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @gksdmsgP have you read my answer and code above ? any feedback ?

Comment: Thank you! As for the comment in the line before last, I am trying to select all the cells from rnga to rnga.End(xlDown). My code for that is as follows: Set rngar = Range(rnga, rnga.End(xlDown)). The .Select will bring another error. I also went ahead and fixed my code to define rngar as a range. I am selecting  all these cells because eventually I would like to copy it to another workbook. Is my code for rngar headed towards the right direction? Thanks again!

Comment: @gksdmsgP  if u took my code and used that line it should work, isn't it ?

Comment: Your code worked, but once I un-comment the last line before end if, I get another 1004 error (unable to get the select property of the range class)

Comment: @gksdmsgP see edited code, there's no need to `Select` the range, after you `Set` it, just `Copy` it.

Comment: Great!! Thank you a bunch